# Inkscape and Document Propertie through the command line

Tags: svg, command, line, inkscape

I use Inkscape to scale and crop SVG files. I do this by using Document Properties (Shift+Ctrl+d) and changing the custom size (and resize page).

However I have a lot of svg files, so I would like to do this through the command line.

Can I access these properties through the --verb command?

Regards
Lars G

Comment: There's a command for resizing the page to the content or selection, but there is nothing for scaling the whole document or even specific objects. You'd need to use a script to automatically edit your SVG text files. You could also write an extension, there are helper functions already available for scaling that you could import.